# Record a video of the screen using .NET technologies

Tags: c#, .net, video, capture, video-capture

Is there a way to record the screen, either desktop or window, using .NET technologies?

My goal is something free. I like the idea of small, low CPU usage, and simple, but I would consider other options if they created a better final product.

In a nutshell, I know how to take a screenshot in C#, but how would I record the screen, or area of the screen, as a video?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There isn’t any need for a third-party DLL. This simple method captures the current screen image into a .NET Bitmap object.

```
    private Image CaptureScreen()
    {
        Rectangle screenSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        Bitmap target = new Bitmap(screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height);
        using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height));
        }
        return target;
    }
```

I am sure you can figure out how to capture a smaller portion of the screen, if that is needed :-).

Comment: Thanks, sorry I didn't make that clear enough, that I want to record video of the screen.

Comment: video is just many single frames pressed together, you could take these snapshots and create an AVI out of them pretty easily.

Comment: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/csharp/avi/write_avi.html

Comment: I have considered this option, just threading the bitmaps together. I was just "assuming" there was something more "canned". Kind of like you shouldn't roll your own security API, there is already something better out there.

Comment: Just to save people a search or two, you need the references to `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Drawing` for the above code.

Comment: For anyone that's curious, CopyFromScreen is using BitBlt.

Comment: This answer shouldn't be accepted.

Comment: This answer should not be accepted and is simply not answering the question...

Comment: This answer is now very outdated and is incompatible with newer Windows frameworks (i.e. mixing UWP/WinUI with WinForms)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Windows media Encoder SDK to build a C# application to record the screen. There are in-built options to record the entire desktop, a particular window or a portion of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

There is a DLL file out there that can do it. I don't remember the name of it, but it's used by [Jing](http://www.jingproject.com/). A friend of mine implemented a screen recorder in just a few minutes by using that DLL file, just for testing.  Check out Jing and you'll probably find the DLL file they use.

Comment: I am trying to check out the jing project.  I was given the impression that jing has a limit on the duration of recording that you can do.  Maybe that limit is built right into the dll you are talking about.  Also, it might not be under gpl/lgpl so it may not be "free" strictly speaking.

Comment: In the jing license agreement: Separation of components - [...] Its component parts may not be separated for use [...].

My advice: be safe.

try searching google for: c# screen capture

Comment: Just making sure everyone understands the goal is to record video of the screen, and not a simple bitmap screen capture.

Comment: I have no clue about the licensing deal for that dll. It's probably not open source or even free. But it does record video of the screen.

Comment: I used Jing and works fantastic. but it only works on .net 4 or 3. I want it for .net 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Media Encoder SDK but it is not supported on Windows 7.

Answer (score -2):

You may try this open source utility: [ScreenRecord](http://screenrecord.codeplex.com/)

It's based on AForge.NET.

Comment: Link only answers should be posted as comments. In anycase if some day the link changes, your answer will become invalid. At least mention name of the utility in the answer so that it could be searched even if the link goes down.