# C# capture screen to small video files

Tags: c#, video, screen, capture

Does someone knows how can I capture my computer screen to a video file? I need the file to be as small as possible. I'm using C#. Third party components also welcome.

TY

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397754/record-video-of-screen-using-net-technologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to creating a screen cast, if so this is the best I have used.

http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.asp

It can produce many formats including FLV which can be configured to small file size.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [ScapLib](http://www.scap.Codeplex.com), and see if that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Directly capturing video from the desktop in .net does not seem to be a simple task. Here's an article from c-sharpcorner that might help you out: [Link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/satisharveti/EnhancedDesktopRecorder07222008041309AM/EnhancedDesktopRecorder.aspx).