# Animation tools

Tags: animation

I realize this is not strictly programming related, but hopefully you will let me get away with it.

My group is trying to put together a very short (2 minutes or so) "film" about a new feature to our product.  The feature is trying to solve a particular problem a lot of our customers have.  We do not want to go with live action for displaying the description of the problem we are trying to solve because we feel that the production value of anything we could come up with would be incredibly low and turn off our viewers.  So we would like to make an animation (basically floating clip-art that is animated moving from place to place) while we have someone narrate the problem description.

While flash seems to be a good solution I have some problems with it:

- I need to capture this in a movie format like avi
- It needs to be captured in 1080p, 720p and regular TV def.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a piece of software that can get me where I need to go?

Free is good, but I think I could get my boss to lay down some scratch for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For just some basic here-is-the-screen-this-is-a-slide kinda thing you could use Windows MovieMaker, free and standard. 
And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397754/record-video-of-screen-using-net-technologies) you have some tips on how to create your own screen-captured-AVI file for input.