# Record video within WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, record

I want to create an application that can record video within the application (not webcam but inside the application), so that user can see what happened to that program. Is there any library or API that can do that?

Comment: prolly duplicate of this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397754/record-video-of-screen-using-net-technologies

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to capture screen to be video using C# .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068414/how-to-capture-screen-to-be-video-using-c-sharp-net)