# C# Dispose function giving an error

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, screenshot

I am trying to take screenshot for every 10 miliseconds and set them as a `Picturebox.image` with Timer. For few seconds program runs perfectly but after few seconds program is crashing. I tried to use `Dispose()` Function in the end of the code to clear the memory but Dispose Function also gives an error. (increasing interval of timer doesn't worked)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace gameBot
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public Bitmap screenshot;
        Graphics GFX;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.enabled = true;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            takescreenshot();
        }
        private void takescreenshot()
        {

            screenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, 
            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
            GFX = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);
            GFX.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
            pictureBox1.Image = screenshot;
            screenshot.Dispose();              
        }           
    }
}
```

The error is

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Parameter is not valid."

Also program is using too much RAM before crashing (Maybe it's crashing because of out of memory exception?)
[As you can see in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNZq1.jpg)

Comment: which line throws the exception? maybe the interval is too small for the garbage collector to keep up. wrap disposables in `using`, for example GFX should also be disposed. do a memory profile, and see if the framework can handle with a lower rate. [some existing posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/397754/1132334)

Comment: A bitmap screenshot of your whole screen, every 10 milliseconds - that is, 100 times per second! - is going to eat a lot of memory for sure. If you want to do this you will have to make sure that any big objects are _very_ short-lived and even then one wonders if your garbage collector can keep up with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Graphics.FromImage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage(v=vs.110).aspx):

> You should always call the Dispose method to release the Graphics and
>   related resources created by the FromImage method.

Also, there's no need to keep that Graphics at Class level.

With that in mind, all you need is:

```
public Bitmap screenshot;

private void takescreenshot()
{
    if (screenshot != null)
    {
        screenshot.Dispose();
    }

    screenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    using (Graphics GFX = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot))
    {
        GFX.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
    }
    pictureBox1.Image = screenshot;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing:

```
pictureBox1.Image = screenshot;
screenshot.Dispose();
```

to:

```
var oldScreenshot = pictureBox1.Image;
pictureBox1.Image = screenshot;
GFX.Dispose();
if (oldScreenshot != null)
    oldScreenshot.Dispose;
```

to ensure that the old screenshot is disposed whenever you assign a new one.

Answer (score 0):

1) Actually your first problem "Parameter is not valid." is beacause youre disposing screenshot object.
If you will try to run your takescreenshot() method only once - you will get this error. I assume that happens because you set object "screenshot" to PictureBox1.Image and than immediately dispose it. Thats logical! PictureBox can`t render disposed object.

2) Try to modify your code on button handler like that:

```
    private Object thisLock = new Object();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thr = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {pictureBox1.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        screenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
                        GFX = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);
                        GFX.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0,
                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
                        pictureBox1.Image = screenshot;
                    }));
                }
                Thread.Sleep(10);
        });
        thr.Start();
    }
```

Works fine! The best way is to get event when picturebox finished rendering, But I didn`t find anything about this.