# C# Streaming screen over Network

Tags: c#, wpf, screensharing, desktop-sharing

I'm looking for a framework/toolkit/component or a way, to stream the screen or a specific window/control (Wpf) over the Network. Here are some specifications:

- stream the screen or a specific window/control (Wpf) over local network
- consistently good stream
- it should be performant
- only the video, no audio etc. needed
- no height fps needed
- no specification, how to play the video (Browser, vlc, ...)
- the cursor should not flicker (mostly result of the screenshots)
- easy to handle
- It should not cost 4000$ for streaming a screen ...

There are a lot of similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397754/record-video-of-screen-using-net-technologies/555765#555765), but they are nearly 10 years old. Most of them are answered with: *Take screenshots*, but this let flicker the cursor and costs cpu and I think there are better ways today.

### What's already done

- I have already tested a self-implemented variant with screenshots
  described [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371955/Motion-JPEG-Streaming-Server) with an mjpeg over http.
- I have also tried a variant with [vlc.dotnet](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet), but it seems, that
  it takes also screenshots and isn't very performant.
- I have also searched for payed versions like [FlashBack](https://www.flashbackrecorder.com/sdk/) and
  [zdsoft](https://www.zdsoft.com/store/screen-recorder-sdk/).
- I have also a looked on NVIDIAs [ShadowPlay](https://www.nvidia.com/de-de/geforce/geforce-experience/shadowplay/) and [Shield
  Stream](https://www.nvidia.com/de-de/shield/games/gamestream/).

### The question

Is there any framework/toolkit/component that streams/shares a desktop or a part of it performantly over a local Network? Is there any other modern way to do that? It would be like Microsoft Teams Desktop sharing.

I'm new to this, so I hope you can help me to get this.

Comment: [Asking for libraries is off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Asking abot tools/components leads to opiniated questions, this question could be flagged for closing because of that. Have you searched over already common used protocols like [rdp](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=RDP) or [VNC](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=VNC)?

Comment: Why do you need to build your own, just use someone elses, and spend time at the beach

Comment: I’m asking for a library to solve this, not to discuss what’s better. I’m sure there is a way to achieve this, but I didn’t found it yet.
To clarify: Someone works on the computer and have to share the screen or a part of it over a Network. A Live stream with the specification from above. Others should not interact with it.

Comment: Dunno if OBS Studio would be of any interest here?

Comment: Asking for a library is off topic, this question should be closed

Comment: It would be the same question, if you replace framework/toolkit/component with technology. I haven't ask wich you wich you would prefer, I ask, if there is anything that hit the points of the specification. If you really want, I will change this words. But Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up it with a VNC Nuget like @bradbury9 has proposed. It has best performance.